# segfault when merging chars in C

Tags: c

I am doing a coding challenge for an interview. Getting this error:

```
Reading symbols from Solution...done.
[New LWP 183007]
Core was generated by `./Solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007fb1eb4fdcf8 in ?? ()
```

the code is as follows:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* readline();



/*
 * Complete the 'newPassword' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return a STRING.
 * The function accepts following parameters:
 *  1. STRING a
 *  2. STRING b
 */

/*
 * To return the string from the function, you should either do static allocation or dynamic allocation
 *
 * For example,
 * char* return_string_using_static_allocation() {
 *     static char s[] = "static allocation of string";
 *
 *     return s;
 * }
 *
 * char* return_string_using_dynamic_allocation() {
 *     char* s = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
 *
 *     s = "dynamic allocation of string";
 *
 *     return s;
 * }
 *
 */
char* newPassword(char* a, char* b) {
     int len = strlen(a);
     char* c = "";
     int i = 0;
     for(; i < len; i++){
         strcat(c, &a[i]);
         strcat(c, &b[i]);
     }
     for(int z = i; z < strlen(b); z++){
         strcat(c, &b[z]);
     }
     return c;
}

int main()
{
    FILE* fptr = fopen(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"), "w");

    char* a = readline();

    char* b = readline();

    char* result = newPassword(a, b);

    fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", result);

    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}

char* readline() {
    size_t alloc_length = 1024;
    size_t data_length = 0;

    char* data = malloc(alloc_length);

    while (true) {
        char* cursor = data + data_length;
        char* line = fgets(cursor, alloc_length - data_length, stdin);

        if (!line) {
            break;
        }

        data_length += strlen(cursor);

        if (data_length < alloc_length - 1 || data[data_length - 1] == '\n') {
            break;
        }

        alloc_length <<= 1;

        data = realloc(data, alloc_length);

        if (!data) {
            data = '\0';

            break;
        }
    }

    if (data[data_length - 1] == '\n') {
        data[data_length - 1] = '\0';

        data = realloc(data, data_length);

        if (!data) {
            data = '\0';
        }
    } else {
        data = realloc(data, data_length + 1);

        if (!data) {
            data = '\0';
        } else {
            data[data_length] = '\0';
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

not really a C/C++ person yet so need some insight.

Comment: In `newPassword()`, you wrote `char* c = "";`. This is not allocating any memory for `c` to be written (or I should say one byte only for the string terminator). I think you should probably first read about *strings* and *memory allocation* THEN do this problem — this is whats important if you write in C/C++, after all.

Comment: In C all literal strings, including the empty string `""`, are really arrays of characters. The empty string is an array of one character, the null-terminator. These arrays are *not* allowed to be modified. Any attempt to modify such an array leads to *undefined behavior*. This is why it's recommended to use `const char *` when using pointers to literal strings. When you do e,g, `strcat(c, &a[i]);` you attempt to both modify *and* write out of bounds of the array. Writing out of bounds also leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: There also *another* problem with e.g. `strcat(c, &a[i])`... You seem to want to append just a single character, but that's not how [`strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) works. It appends a *string* to another string. So `&a[i]` is take to be the first character of a null-terminated string, and all of that string will be appended to `c`.

Comment: Lastly, what if `strlen(a) > strlen(b)`? Then your code will go out of bounds of `b`.

Comment: The lesson to learn here: Learn the languages you put on your CV or resume. If you don't know such fundamental parts of the language like shown in this code, then you have to be a quick study to learn them before you attempt interview code challenges.

Answer (score 3):

Your first loop has incorrect bounds. If the length of `a` is longer than the length of the `b`, you access characters beyond the end of `b`. You should have three loops.

1. The first loops as many times as the smaller of the two lengths.
2. The second loop loops over the characters `a` has in excess of `b`.
3. The third loop loops over the characters `b` has in excess of `a`.

---

In C all literal strings, including the empty string `""`, are really arrays of characters. The empty string is an array of one character, the null-terminator. These arrays are not allowed to be modified. Any attempt to modify such an array leads to undefined behavior. This is why it's recommended to use `const char *` when using pointers to literal strings.

Conveniently, we know the new password will be `strlen(a) + strlen(b)` chars in length. Let's call that `n`. So that means you need an array of `n+1` chars in size. (The `+1` is for the NUL.) Using `char c[n+1];` won't do since you want to array to exist beyond the end of the function (since you're returning it). You will therefore need to use `char *c = malloc(n+1);`.

---

Then there's the misuse of `strcat`. Both arguments are expected to be (NUL-terminated) strings. If `a` is `UVW` and `b` is `xyz`, then you are building `UVWxyzVWyzWz` instead of `UxVyWz`. To add a character, since you already have sufficient memory (after the above fix), you can just assign directly to the correct element of the array. Don't forget to terminate it with a NUL.

---

Credit: The first paragraph of the second section was written by [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude).